# How do you get different RVM gemsets to use different versions of Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm working with RVM, and I made the mistake of installing the latest version of Rails (3.2.5) without creating a gemset first.

Now, a project I'm working on requires Rails 3.0.0 to be compatible, but when I create a new gemset, install Rails 3.0.0 and check my Rails version, it still says I've got 3.2.5

Do I just need to uninstall Rails from everywhere and reinstall into separate gemsets for this to work?

Comment: Have you tried switching the ruby version with the command `rvm 3.0.0`?

Comment: It's the not the ruby version I'm trying to switch, but the Rails version. Using ruby 1.9.3, if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that. After you create the new gemset, are you switching to it before install Rails 3.0.0?

Comment: Yeah. I switch using the command rvm use 1.9.3@rails3old and then install Rails 3.0.0

Comment: Do you see mulitple versions listed for rails when you run `gem list`?

Comment: Is there any reason to not use `bundler` for this?

Comment: I do not. It just lists rails 3.2.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `gem list -d rails` you'll get an output similar to this.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.2.3)
    Author: David Heinemeier Hansson
    Homepage: http://www.rubyonrails.org
    Installed at: /Users/bjedrocha/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@jwb

    Full-stack web application framework.
```

Note the `installed at` directive. The part after the `@` indicates the gemset. So if you've installed Rails without first creating and switching to a named gemset, chances are that it is installed under the `@global` gemset (a default for RVM). If this is your case, I would switch into the global gemset and uninstall Rails. Once its uninstalled, you can switch back to your named gemset and it will use the Rails version installed in this gemset

```
rvm use 1.9.3@global
gem uninstall rails

rvm use 1.9.3@mygemset
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad to hear that worked! Can you accept my answer for others who stumble upon this question? Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Rails 3.2.5 is a member of your global gemset, whose installations are inherited by each of that ruby's gemsets.

I would first take stock your gemsets with `rvm gemset list`, see if there's a difference between @global and the new gemset, and uninstall gems from the @global gemset if needed.

I think most of what you need to know is here:
https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/